# access the current unittest.TestCase instance

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm writing some testing utility library and may want to do the following

```
def assertSomething(test_case, ...):
  test_case.assertEqual()
```

Is there a way to skip passing test_case around? e.g.

```
def assertSomething(...):
  get_current_unittest_case().assertEqual()
```

Answer (score 1):

### `AssertionError`

If you just want to do some checks and fail with custom message,
raising `AssertionError` (via `raise` or `assert`) is the way to
go. By default, [`TestCase.failureException`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.failureException)
[is `AssertionError`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f446bee4f6ac0c61bb2c3386a0149fd36855793/Lib/unittest/case.py#L384), and
[`fail`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.fail)
(which internally is used by convenience methods of `unittest.TestCase`)
just raises it.

`test_things.py`:

```
import unittest


def check_is_zero(number):
    assert number == 0, "{!r} is not 0".format(number)


def check_is_one(number):
    if number != 1:
        raise AssertionError("{!r} is not 1".format(number))


class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        check_is_one(1)

    def test_zero(self):
        check_is_zero(0)
```

### `TestCase` mixin

An easy and relatively readable way to add new assertions is to
make a “mixin class” that test cases will subclass. Sometimes it
is good enough.

`testutils.py` that contains mixin:

```
class ArithmeticsMixin:

    def check_is_one(self, number):
        self.assertEqual(number, 1)
```

`test_thing.py`, actual tests:

```
import unittest

import testutils


class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase, testutils.ArithmeticsMixin):

    def test_one(self):
        self.check_is_one(1)
```

If there will be many mixin classes, use of base one may help:

```
import unittest

import testutils


class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase, testutils.ArithmeticsMixin):
    """Test case with additional methods for testing arithmetics."""


class NumbersTest(BaseTestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        self.check_is_one(1)
```

### Thread local and `TestCase` subclass

Less readable is use of special base class,
[thread local](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html#thread-local-data)
(like global, but is aware of threads) and getter function.

`testutils.py`:

```
import unittest
import threading


_case_data = threading.local()  # thread local


class ImproperlyUsed(Exception):
    """Raised if get_case is called without cooperation of BaseTestCase."""


def get_case():  # getter function
    case = getattr(_case_data, "case", None)
    if case is None:
        raise ImproperlyUsed
    return case


class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):  # base class

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        _case_data.case = self
        super().run(*args, **kwargs)
        _case_data.case = None


def check_is_one(number):
    case = get_case()
    get_case().assertEqual(number, 1)
```

When test case is running, `self` (test case instance) is saved as
`_case_data.case`, so later inside `check_is_one` (or any other function
that is called from inside of test method and wants to access `self`)
`get_case` will be able to get reference to test case instance. Note
that after running `_case_data.case` is set to `None`, and if
`get_case` is called after that, `ImproperlyUsed` will be raised.

`test_thing.py`:

```
import testutils


def check_is_zero(number):  # example of out-of-testutils function
    testutils.get_case().assertEqual(number, 0)


class NumbersTest(testutils.BaseTestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        testutils.check_is_one(1)

    def test_zero(self):
        check_is_zero(0)
```

### s̻̙ỵ̞̜͉͎̩s.̠͚̱̹̦̩͓_̢̬ge̡̯̳̖t̞͚̖̳f̜̪̩̪r̙̖͚̖̼͉̹a͏ṃ̡̹e̞̝̱̠̙

Finally, [`sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys._getframe).
Let’s just h́o̞̓̐p̆̇̊̇e you don’t need it, because it is part of CPython,
not Python.

`testutils.py`:

```
import sys
import unittest


class ImproperlyUsed(Exception):
    """Raised if get_case can't get "self" TestCase instance."""


def get_case():
    case = sys._getframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals.get("self")
    if not isinstance(case, unittest.TestCase):
        raise ImproperlyUsed
    return case


def check_is_one(number):
    case = get_case()
    get_case().assertEqual(number, 1)
```

`sys._getframe` returns frame from the top of call stack, then few
frames below `f_locals` is taken, and there is `self`: instance of
`unittest.TestCase`. Like in previous implementation option, there is
sanity check, but here it is done with `isinstance`.

`test_things.py`:

```
import unittest

import testutils


def check_is_zero(number):  # example of out-of-testutils function
    testutils.get_case().assertEqual(number, 0)


class NumbersTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        testutils.check_is_one(1)

    def test_zero(self):
        check_is_zero(0)
```

---

If you just want to provide `assertEqual` for some new type,
take a look at [`addTypeEqualityFunc`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.addTypeEqualityFunc).